# Is there a shorthand way to setState() in React?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

Lets say I initialize the state of a component like so:

```
getInitialState: function(){
   return {name: "Bob Smith",
           phone: "555-555-5555",
           location: "San Francisco, CA",
           best-friend: "Bill Jacobson",
           favorite-color: "Orange"}
},
```

Then if I just want to modify one of those states I was told that the following was a no-no:

```
this.state.name = "John Smith";
```

But rather I should use:

```
this.setState({name: "John Smith",
               phone: this.state.phone,
               location: this.state.location,
               best-friend: this.state.best-friend,
               favorite-color: this.state.favorite-color});
```

There must be a more efficient way to do this. Is there a shorthand way to change just one property of my state object in a way that is safe for react?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually, you do not have to specify all the values. Only the one you would like to have a new value for.

`setState` will only add (or subsequently overwrite) values to your state. It will not re-create the whole object.

You can find the relevant documentation [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate). Facebook developers also thought about the exact same question you raised here and under the hood they keep the old values, and I'm quoting here:

> The first argument can be an object (containing zero or more keys to update) or a function (of state and props) that returns an object containing keys to update.

Comment: Please note that this only works for top-level state. You'll be unable to do this for any nested state.

Comment: This is perfect thanks! Just out of curiosity why is it not conventional to use this.state.name = newValue other than "Facebook doesn't like it"? 
EDIT: I just answered this myself by scrolling down 20 lines in the documentation! Thanks for the original answer.

Comment: @EllDoubleYew Because your changes can very easily get lost. The internal component state management that React does for you as well as all the component lifecycle methods which are exposed to you do not play along well with direct outside value setting. It is one of the reasons why React goes hand-in-hand with immutable data structures and why the Flux architecture fits into the big picture so perfectly (be that Flux, Redux or any other implementation of it).

Answer (score 3):

Yes it's built into React! As Elod said, you only have to specify the state that you are changing. The rest of the state will remain the same.

```
getInitialState: function() {
  return {
    name: "Bob Smith",
    phone: "555-555-5555",
    location: "San Francisco, CA",
  }
}

// Somewhere else...
this.setState({
  name: "John Smith",
})
```

`this.state` is now

```
{
  name: "John Smith",
  phone: "555-555-5555",
  location: "San Francisco, CA",
}
```